# Omittance of Relative Pronoun

Tags: grammar, pronouns, that

### **Below is the excerpt from English Proficiency Test**

***Our professional designers produce high-quality custom logo designs (a) that exhibit just the image (b) that our clients want to project.***

**Question 1** Are there any difference between (a) that or (b) that grammatically?

If so, what would be the proper term for denoting their difference?

**Question 2**
In informal style, one can leave out the relative pronoun. However, as far as I know, this leave-out permitted only in case of in that relative clauses, the relative pronoun denotes the intention/object of the verb.

In addition to it, we can’t leave out the relative pronoun when it is the subject of the verb in infinite relative clauses. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: The term you use "infinite" (in the last paragraph) is quite odd to me. Did you mean "infinitive" or "non-finite"?